# Why is a DC base voltage needed to attain faithful amplification?

Tags: transistors, bjt

I was studying about transistor biasing from an article, http://1drv.ms/1yU8B7C, and I have a question regarding this part:

[image: Fig 9.1]

Why should an extra voltage \$V_{BB}\$ be needed when there is already an voltage \$V_{CC}\$ available to produce \$I_c\$ current?

Comment: I guess once you bias it, to turn it on, from then it acts in a linear/active region, and your input signal is properly used to amplify. Without having the transistor ready for action, your input signal would need to first overcome the transistor's OFF properties. Just a guess, i'm not really a transistor pro.

Comment: The bias voltage generally needs to be somewhere between the positive and negative rails of VCC.  It doesn't have to come from a separate supply, however.  It may be (and often is) generating using resistors.  When experimenting with an amplifier circuit, however, it may be more convenient to use a separate adjustable supply for VBB than to generate it using resistors.

Answer (score 2):

Because of how transistors work. If you consider the NPN bipolar transistors for example (the ones on your diagram), they only amplify the input signal if the base is positively charged with respect to the emitter: that's when the isolation layer (called depletion layer) that spontaneously form between the base and the emitter is no longer enough to stop electrons from crossing and entering the base, forming the base current. If the collector is also biased positively with respect to the base (meaning, low positive voltage on the base, higher voltage on the collector), most of the electrons that will have crossed the gap will be sucked up into the collector, forming a higher collector current. Base current and collector current are in this way sort of proportional, you get amplification.

If you don't bias the base positively and just connect an AC source, half of the time the base will be negatively biased, strengthening the depletion layer and you'll get close to no current in the collector. The transistor is off, no amplification and in fact no current at all: that's why your output sinewave is clipped to zero for negative voltages.

Therefore you need to bias the base at half of the maximum voltage of your AC signal if you want to make sure the base never goes below conduction.

[image]
<sub>(source: [learnabout-electronics.org](http://www.learnabout-electronics.org/images/image316.png))</sub>

Above a random picture I picked from [internet](https://www.learnabout-electronics.org/Semiconductors/bjt_03.php) to illustrate what I'm saying. Apparently there is an animation on that page too, should you want to visualise it.

For completion, PNP bipolar transistors work the same way with different polarities. There are also different transistor families, the main "competitor" being field effect transistors.

Comment: But why are electrons "sucked" into the collector, when the depletion layer is stopping them? Is it because the collector is filled with "high amounts of holes"?

Comment: Excellent question, I asked the same thing when it wasn't clear in my head, and Alfred Centauri gave a good answer here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/129624/if-the-depletion-layer-of-a-transistor-collector-base-junction-is-thick-why-are
Basically the depletion layer is made to isolate the semiconductors from eachother, but the free electrons in the base are of an opposite polarity to the base holes, so they're encouraged by the field to cross the depletion layer however thick it is.

Comment: @Mister Mystère:could you tell me how the depletion region is strengthened by applying reverse bias?

Comment: Reverse bias means that you're applying a voltage that creates an electric field that prevents the electrons (in a NPN transistor, holes in a PNP) from crossing the junction. The electric field is created by having positive charges at one end (+ terminal) and negative charges at the other (- terminal). Connect the + terminal to the N region and the - terminal to the P region and the electrons will be repelled by the - terminal, they'll never cross the junction and most of them will cram away from it.

Comment: Does that answer your question or is it still unclear?

Answer (score 0):

Bipolar transistor are "current control" device. The \$I_{c}\$ are "controlled" by \$I_{b}\$, so you must have a voltage source (some times a current source may ok) to bias the base-emitter to supply \$I_{b}\$. Please read the book carefully. I think it will show you better than me.

Answer (score 0):

Read some more and build some circuits.  There are several transistor models.  At it's simplest a transistor has only one polarity.  It only controls current flow in one direction.  So for an npn you need to push current into the base to get current to flow from C to E.  Pulling current out of the base, (base negative with respect to the emitter) does nothing.

Comment: :But do you think that without Vbb an Ic current can't be obtained.

Comment: Absolutely!  Vbb is normally called Vbe.  Unless Vbe is positive there will be no collector current. (for an npn)  Simple models assume a transistor is a current controlled device, but the next level up, you will find it's often better to think of it in terms of Vbe,  Ebers-Moll equation and all that.

Comment: :why couldn't we obtain Ic with Vcc.

Comment: \$V_{BB}\$ is NOT the same thing as \$V_{BE}\$. The former refers to the "base bias" (usually DC) voltage that is added to the input signal, while the latter refers to the instantaneous voltage directly across the device. \$V_{BB}\$ needs to be larger than the greatest negative swing of the input signal in order to insure that \$V_{BE}\$ is always positive and that the transistor is always conducting. If the transistor is ever completely cut off (or saturated), that's when distortion occurs.

Comment: @DaveTweed, OK fair enough.  (Should I remove my comment?)

Answer (score 0):

"*Why should an extra voltage VBB be needed when there is already an voltage VCC available to produce Ic current?*"

If this would be correct, you would describe the properties of a resistive two-pole.
But the transistor has three nodes. And it is a device that can be used for amplification purposes. Hence, you need a third terminal for connecting the signal to be amplifed.
And - more that that - because the transistor is strongly non-linear you must bring the device to quiescent conditions (dc current Ic) which allow operation in the quasi-linear region of the input-output characteristics. And that is done by a bias voltage between base and emitter. Remember the properties of a simple pn diode: A voltage of at least 0.6 volts (app.) is needed to "open" the diode.